# C freeing 2D array if malloc fail

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free

If i have a 2D array allocated as follows:

```
int** map;
map = malloc(number * sizeof(int*));
if(!(map)){
    printf("out of memory!\n");
    return 1;
}
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
    map[i] = malloc(number * sizeof(int));
    if (!(map[i])){
        printf("Not enough memory!\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

If the allocation fails and we enter in the if statement should i free map and the "columns" allocated until now? If so, how should i do it?

Right now i just print the message and return 1 but i'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: You don't have a 2D array. That's a pointer-based look-up table. To allocate a 2D array, you have to use `int (*map)[number] = malloc(sizeof (int[number][number]));` or equivalent. The difference, namely that a 2D array has its data allocated in adjacent memory cells, is very important to understand.

Comment: Don't forget to check the return value of the outer malloc.

Comment: @Lundin Oh i didn't know that, apart from the fact that the data is allocated differently are there any other differences in how to use them/speed?

Comment: @user464502 i had forgot that, fixed. Thanks

Comment: @JohnSmith The only advantage of the method you use is that it allows each "dimension" of the look up table to get a different size than the others and change the size in run-time. The disadvantages are that your method leads to heap segmentation, much slower program due to cache misses and needlessly complex code that has potential for bugs and memory leaks. Also the actual allocation time is much slower with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
if (!(map[i])){
    printf("Not enough memory!\n");

    while (--i>=0)
        free(map[i]);

    free(map);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you should `free()` otherwise you leak memory which might matter if this is in a long-running program.

One way to make it easier is to compute the total size of all the allocations, and do a single larger `malloc()` rather than a whole bunch of smaller ones. This is also (potentially much) faster, since heap allocations can be expensive.

That way, you only need to check once if it succeeded or failed, and there's nothing to `free()` in case of failure.

Something like this:

```
int ** map_allocate(size_t number)
{
  int **base = malloc(number * sizeof (int *) + number * number * sizeof (int));
  if(base != NULL)
  {
    int *row = (int *) (base + number);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < number; ++i)
      base[i] = row + i * number;
  }
  return base;
}
```

I didn't test-run this, but something along those lines.

Comment: mh, is it still faster for really big maps which are accessed a lot or is it potentially slower in the long run since i have to calculate where my number is every time? If it's almost always faster i might actually use a solution similar to yours (i need to shave off as much time as i can from my program's execution)

Comment: @JohnSmith What? I didn't propose any different data structure, nothing to "calculate where my number is" whatever that means, all I offered was an alternative way of *allocating* the array of arrays. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Always set pointers to null immediately you allocate them.

```
int **map;

map = malloc(number * sizeof(int *));
if(!map)
    goto out_of_memory;
for(i=0;i<number;i++)
    map[i] = 0;

for(i=0;i<numbers;i++)
{
    map[i] = malloc(number * sizeof(int));
    if(!map[i])
        goto out_of_memory;
}

...

return 0;

out_of_memory:
    if(map)
        for(i=0;i<number;i++)
            free(map[i]);
    free(map);
    return -1;
```